# setting up npm package directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've put together a little library called Mockery (**edit:** now called [pretendr](http://github.com/nathanmacinnes/pretendr) because there's another project called mockery), and I want to put it in npm. The library has directories called `lib` and `test` for the source files and unit tests respectively. I have the following in my package.json:

```
"files" : [
   "Makefile",
   "README.md",
   "lib/",
   "lib/mockery.js",
   "test/",
   "test/runner.js",
   "test/tests.js"
],
"directories" : {
    "lib" : "lib",
    "test" : "test"
},
"main" : "lib/mockery"
```

But for some reason, everything in my `lib` directory just seems to go in the root directory of my npm module. The `test` directory works automatically (even if I don't include the `"directories"` part of the package.json). How can I make npm put my lib directory contents in the correct place?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not because of the directories entry, but you have "lib/" under a files entry, too. According to [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

> The  "files" field is an array of files to include in your project.
>      If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder.
>      (Unless they would be ignored by another rule.)

Comment: Added that into the question. So how should I include the files inside the lib folder?

Comment: The link in your answer is broken, please correct it. Also, can you provide information for the `files` and `directories` fields? I can't figure out what they are used for.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked it out... it was a really silly mistake. Turns out there's a package called `mockery`, and mine is called `Mockery`, and they just looked very similar in directory file names. That's the problem with standard ways of doing things!